# Sublime Text: Different Snippet for JavaScript ES5 vs ES6?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sublimetext

I have these [snippets I use regularly when writing tests in Jasmine](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers-Snippets), an example of one is;

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
beforeEach(function() {
});
]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>be</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

What I'm wondering is (possibly using the `<scope>` value?) if the output could be different based on the current Language between JavaScript, JavaScriptNext — ES6 Syntax, and JSX? But as far as I do, do these all share the `source.js` scope?

The output I would want is;

**JavaScript**

```
beforeEach(function() {

});
```

**JavaScriptNext — ES6 Syntax, and JSX**

```
beforeEach(() => {

});
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The `scope` depends on the syntax you are using for the file.
The ES6 syntax highlighters uses `source.js` for compatibility reasons.
[babel-sublime/JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/blob/master/JavaScript%20(Babel).sublime-syntax#L7)
[JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage/JavaScriptNext.YAML-tmLanguage](https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage/blob/master/JavaScriptNext.YAML-tmLanguage#L3)
Some syntax (e.g. Markdown) may specify a portion of text `source.js`, which will then be handled by the ES6 syntax.

You could have forked JSNext syntax and use another scope, say `source.js.es6`.

I recommend [facelessuser/ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) for checking scopes.